# combining userProfile table and role table in one view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im new in asp.net mvc, im having difficulty in combining this 2 tables which i have added through ado.net. im having errors in my code. please check in image.

images here
[image: My custom class]

[image: My controller image link]

And in creating view. i have no idea how to implement it. please anyone guide me. thank you

This is my controller

```
WebsiteEntities1 websiteDB = new WebsiteEntities1();

        public ActionResult AccountsListing()
        {
            var viewModel = from o in websiteDB.UserProfiles
                            join o2 in websiteDB.webpages_Roles
                               on o.UserId equals o2.UserProfiles
                            where o.UserId.Equals(o2.UserProfiles)
                            select new InsertBreweryModel
                            { userProfileData = o, rolesData = o2 };
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

---

This is my model class

```
namespace APWebsite.Models
{
    public class AccountsCustomView
    {
        public UserProfile userProfileData { get; set; }
        public webpages_Roles rolesData { get; set; }

    }
}
```

---

and no idea how to implement in view

Comment: post code of your class as code please, not as picture

Comment: im sorry about that sir. i added my code sir.

Comment: i can be wrong, what's error do you have? can you post it?

Comment: in "join". which is red line in image 2

Answer (score 0):

You joining field with table it's just wrong i think you should do it like this:

```
 var viewModel = from o in websiteDB.UserProfiles
                 join o2 in websiteDB.webpages_Roles
                 on o.UserId equals o2.UserId //check this line 
                 select new InsertBreweryModel 
                 { 
                     userProfileData = o, 
                     rolesData = o2 
                 };
```

Your `webpages_Roles` should have field with `UserId` it could have different name, but you should join it like this.

Now as your `viewModel` is `IEnumerable<AccountsCustomView>` type you can do on your `AccountsListing` View like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<APWebsite.Models.AccountsCustomView>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    item.userProfileData.UserName //here you can do anything with your data.
}
```

Comment: sir. im having red line in "join"